# How to create new branch on GIthub without checking out locally and pushing?

Tags: github

Here I am talking only about [GitHub](https://github.com)

I created 1 repository so i am owner of that repository.

Default there is 1 branch called master.

Now I used bitbucket but in bitbucket if we go to branches they provide option to create new branch directly there.

[image]

Why GitHub is not allowing to create new branch directly there?
Is there any setting I am missing / they have any documentation for that?

[image]

**Edit** :-

I already tried by typing name but it doesnt allow me to create new branch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type your branch name here, there will be a new button at the bottom.

[image: Create branch]